# How to exploit existing closed-form update in stochastic coordinate descent?

Tags: expectation-maximization, stochastic-approximation, coordinate-descent

I want to minimize a loss function $L(\Theta \mid X)$ given data $X = \{x_1,\dots,x_D\}$ where $D$ is large.
The loss can be decomposed as: $L(\Theta \mid X) = \sum_{d=1}^D l(\Theta \mid x_d)$ where each $l$ is non-convex.
The domain of $\Theta$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, with various constraints along each or multiple dimensions, e.g. nonnegativity or simplex constraints.
I want to perform (mini-batched) online learning over the loss $L$.
While it might be possible to do stochastic gradient descent using reparameterization (e.g. taking the exponential, optimize in softmax representation), I was provided closed form solution $\boldsymbol G$ such that $\Theta^{(t+1)} = \boldsymbol G(\Theta^{(t)})$, where $\Theta_i^{(t+1)}=G_i(\Theta^{(t)})$ is the minimizer of $L(\Theta_1^{(t)}, \dots, \Theta_{i-1}^{(t)}, \Theta_i, \Theta_{i+1}^{(t)}, \dots, \Theta_n^{(t)} \mid X)$, and I want to exploit that. I plan to use some sort of coordinate descent algorithm that runs given each (mini-batched) $x_d$'s rather than the entire $X$. Here goes my question: **How should I make use of $\boldsymbol G$ to achieve my online/mini-batched learning goal?**

If you find the about description abstract, here is an example. In [(Hoffman et al., 2010)](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2010/file/71f6278d140af599e06ad9bf1ba03cb0-Paper.pdf) the authors suggested maximizing the score function (evidence lower bound) $\mathcal L(\boldsymbol w,\boldsymbol\phi,\boldsymbol\gamma,\boldsymbol\lambda)=\sum_d l(n_d,\phi_d,\gamma_d,\boldsymbol\lambda)$ via stochastic variational inference. The EM updates have closed-form solutions (Equation (5) in the paper). Algorithm 2 of the paper gives a solution on how to do stochastic coordinate descent, but I find the evaluation order of $\gamma,\phi,\lambda$ obscure. I also learned about stepwise (online) EM [(Liang and Klein, 2009)](https://aclanthology.org/N09-1069.pdf), which appears related to my question. However, their notation is too abstract and I couldn't understand.

While providing the example, I'd prefer answers that facilitate insights on my bolded question statement rather than clarification of the specific example. If the underlying solution to my question does not typically generalize (which I have no idea about), explanation regarding the example paper about the following is also welcomed: *(a)* why the order "phi -> gamma -> phi -> gamma ... (until gamma converged) -> lambda -> phi -> gamma -> phi -> gamma ..." works? and *(b)* why only the lambda update requires convex combination between old and new values, whereas the gamma and phi update rules needn't?